# Problema con el pie de página en Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Tengo un problema con los pies de página en Bootstrap. El problema es que consigo que se sitúe en la parte de abajo de la página, pero cuando le digo que tenga un margin top con respecto al elemento anterior, lo ignora y el último contenido queda tapado con el pie de página.

Aquí pongo una simulación de lo que me sucede. ¿Cómo se podría solucionar? Gracias

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Pruebas</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Reproduccion del error</h1>

    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>
    
    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>
    
    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>
    
    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>
    
    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <p>PEasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <p>PAdasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <p>PUdasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <footer class="footer bg-primary fixed-bottom mt-5 py-3">
        <div class="container" align="center">
          <span>Pie de pagina</span>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

El tener el `<footer>` con `position: fixed` provoca que el elemento salga del flujo normal que tiene dentro del **DOM** (similar a cuando posicionas a un elemento con `position: absolute`). El resto de elementos no van a contemplar el espacio que ocupa, por lo que por mucho margen superior que le des jamás vas a conseguir empujar al resto del contenido.

Una solución podría ser darle `padding` suficiente a la parte inferior del `<body>` como para que contemple el tamaño que ocupa el pie de página.

```css
body {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Pruebas</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Reproduccion del error</h1>

    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>
    
    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>
    
    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>
    
    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>
    
    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <p>dadasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <p>PEasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <p>PAdasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <p>PUdasdsasafsafsffsfsfsfsfsfsfsggdsgggdgsdgsdgsgsgdsgdsdgdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsddsdddddddddddddddddd</p>

    <footer class="footer bg-primary fixed-bottom mt-5 py-3">
        <div class="container" align="center">
          <span>Pie de pagina</span>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfecto! Con esa respuesta me ha quedado todo claro. Mil gracias.